# Should you straighten UVs even when it causes stretching?

Tags: uv

Everyone says you should straighten UVs wherever possible. But this causes some stretching, when and where should you straighten uvs, and where would you NOT straighten them?
[image]
[image]

Comment: The result is that there will be relatively more detail on the parts that are elongated and relatively less detail on the parts that are shortened, but it's entirely up to you to decide if it's something you want or not. I wouldn't worry too much about it in this case, since the relative elongation is homogeneous along your band of faces, you won't notice a visible change in texture detail density. Again, it's up to your workflow to decide wether it's a problem or not.

Comment: Thanks! This was just a basic example I whipped up, but what if you have islands that are heterogenous?  When I don't straighten uvs, I get some pretty noticeable aliasing/when baking high to low, especially on round/curved objects, even when baking in substance painter at 4k with 4x4 Anti aliasing turned on. Which i shouldn't have to do to get quality bakes.

Comment: One thing you can do is download quality assets online (there are a lot of Creative commons downloadable ones over on sketchfab) and study how they are uv unwrapped

Comment: Great idea, Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

UV mapping is used to display 2d textures on a 3d surfaces - that's all there is to it. There are absolutely no rules here. You can do whatever you want however you want as long as it gives you your desired results. Generally you mostly want to avoid stretching, but that's not a rule at all. You may want to stretch some textures on purpose to get some specific effect. You should manipulate the UVs in a way that matches your idea of how the texture should look on your 3d object.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I was just trying to better understand an industry standard workflow for game assets, what if you're baking from high poly to low poly though? There are definitely some rules, no? texel density,  where your seams should go in terms of hard edges, not to mention the terrible aliasing problems with curved/round islands.

Comment: There are no "rules", just things people do for stuff to work. Also there is no such thing as "industry standard" if you ask me. Just do what works. Stretching will probably not happen on geometry in your picture just because of straight lines. Scale the UVs in one axis at a time to see if it helps. The scale is probably not uniform after however you straighten the UVs. It's hard to see the actual problem from images you show. If you edit the question and add more detail about the problem(like for example show the actual texture stretching), maybe you could get a better answer.